Pass function name and multiple params as string
I have an object of functions id, names and parameters.
I want to call the object with an id, that will execute the corresponding function by its string name and passes the associated array parameters.
var funcList = {
  "0abc1": {
    fn: "myFunc1",
    args: ["red", "green"]

  },
  "1def2": {
    fn: "myFunc2",
    args: ["blue"]

  }
};


  const func = funcList["0abc1"];
  const funcName = func.fn;
  const funcParams = func.args;

  window[funcName](funcParams.toString());

When the function has one parameter it works. But doesen't work with multiple parameters.
Is there a better way to implemented it or correct it ?

Note that this has nothing to do with jQuery so I've removed it from your title and tags

Ok I get it. Thanks

Spread ... your arguments Array:
var funcList = {
  "0abc1": { fn: "myFunc1", args: ["red", "green"]},
  "1def2": { fn: "myFunc2", args: ["blue"]}
};

const func = funcList["0abc1"];
window[func.fn](...func.args);


Thanks Roko. It works like I wanted. Thanks a lot !
